# Unity and Facebook Missing App Link URL

Tags: android, facebook, facebook-graph-api, unity-game-engine, applinks

I am trying to create on unity where when I click a button I get taken to invite someone to use the app. I have been able to get to that process but when it comes to clicking the invite button it says the following:

```
Missing App Link Url
The app link used with this invite does not contain and Android URL.
```

I have looked at every video, article and document I could find and cant find any way of making this work with unity.

I have the facebook sdk and login,logout, share work fine.

I have seen in the sdk settings on unity there is a place for app link but I dont understand what has to go there.

https://gyazo.com/31bdb85b5b5d39acafbe0452d7faa98c

I am trying to use https://manage.appurl.io/ but it does not seem to be working. Could someone explain the steps needed to get the share function to work.

I sore on one post that I had to generate fb url but that no longer works when I go to the url.

```
public void Invite()
{


    FB.Mobile.AppInvite (
        new Uri("https://appurl.io/jaidx0qh"),
        new Uri("https://i.gyazo.com/c9d956294974024a5d09e57768e824e8.png"),
        InviteCallback
    );
}
```

Answer (score 0):

That error typically means that FB is unable to find meta tags on your webpage (see below). You can debug your url in [FB debugger](https://developers.facebook.com/tools/debug/) to check your meta tags

```
<head>
    <meta property="al:ios:url" content="example://applinks" />
    <meta property="al:ios:app_store_id" content="12345" />
    <meta property="al:ios:app_name" content="Example App" />
    <meta property="og:title" content="example page title" />
    <meta property="og:type" content="website" />
    <!-- Other headers -->
</head>
```

Also note: With the release of the Facebook SDK version 4.28.0, App Invites is deprecated. It will be supported until February 5, 2018. [(link)](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/app-invites/ios)

Comment: Viral I read the same thing about App Invited depreciation, however that message only shows on the Android SDK section and not under FB.Mobile.AppInvite in the Unity SDK section - so I wonder if the depreciation is only for the Android invite APIs and won't affect the Unity ones. Maybe you have some insight on this?

Comment: Hi, the message appears on both platforms (iOS and Android) and will be applicable to all their sdks, including unity. You should look for alternatives like Whatsapp, FB Messenger and other popular chat application to drive your organic growth.